# Slow update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

When i try to update my torrents table (My torrent site permits to share only open source stuff) with the following query

```
    UPDATE `torrents` SET `leech` = '0', `seed` = '1' WHERE `id` = '26784'
```

It take approximaty 0.5 seconds to update a table which contains only 20,000 records . My other queries are executed in less than 0.0478s (SELECT queries)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `torrents` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`hash_info` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`category_slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`age` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`trackers` longtext NOT NULL,
`magnet` longtext,
`files` longtext,
`parent_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`publish_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`uploader` int(11) NOT NULL,
`seed` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`leech` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`file_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`comments_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26816 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any solution ?

Comment: upvoted for the table name `torrents` ;) .. world will not end in 0.5 seconds, it is negligible. Some external factors could be the reason

Comment: My other queries are executed in less than 0.0478s so i think , this is problem;)

Comment: Here `20.000` do you mean `20` or `20000`

Comment: Sry , i mean 20000

Comment: then you can create index on  `id` column to reduce the time taken..

Comment: it takes the same time :(

Comment: Am not a Mysql expert. Lets wait for someone

Comment: Can you update the create table to show your change?  ... and maybe also run an explain on the query and show this output too.

Comment: What kind of queries are executed in less than 1 sec? Are general queries? How long does it take to query for an specific id? Do you have anything else like constraints, triggers, etc on that table?

Comment: `SELECT `torrents`.*, `users`.`nickname` AS `nickname`
FROM `torrents`
JOIN `users` ON `torrents`.`uploader` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `torrents`.`id` = '22064-pack+nintendo+-+nes+mini' ` this kind of query

Comment: Mysql stores data in 8KB files called pages. Every time SQL loads anything it needs to read these 8KB pages into memory and the more records you can fit inside these pages the faster the query will be. It appears like you may have very few records per page. Try splitting seed and leech into a separate table if you are updating these frequently.

Comment: Correction InnoDB is default 16KB

Comment: @MIKE good idea i ll test right now ty

Comment: 56 bytes for header, 8 bytes for footer, Id(4), Leech(4), Seed(4) = 12 bytes. 16,000 bytes per page. You can fit 1328 records in a single page for this table - extremely fast.

Comment: If you and the server are 1000KM apart, then part of the delay could be the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Lookups based on the indexed columns are much faster than the lookups on the non-indexed columns. This behavior can be case more visible with the growing amount of the data.

Create an index on Id column and check if it helps you improve the performance of the query.

Comment: I obtain the same result

Comment: Then it may not be the query problem.

Could you add 20k and 40k more records in the table and run the update query? If there is a problem with query the performance of the query should degrade significantly. If its taking almost the same time it would some other infrastructure problem.

Comment: Done all my other queries are running faster than this update query than is executed in 1.2second

Comment: So it is it taking 0.5 sec with  20k rec and 1.2 sec with 40k rec? How much time did it take for updating a record when table is having 60k rec?

Answer (score 0):

`id` is declared to be an integer.  So, first your comparison should be to an integer not a string:

```
UPDATE `torrents`
    SET `leech` = '0', `seed` = '1'
    WHERE `id` = 26784;
```

Second, you need an index on the id.  You can create one by:

```
create index idx_torrents_id on torrents(id);
```

Alternatively, make it a primary key in the table.

Comment: Sry , I obtain the same result :(

Comment: @KurtKoben - Please update the Question with the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` _after_ adding the PK.